# inject html code to all port 80 request

Tags: html, proxy, inject

I am looking for the best solution to inject some html ad code into every webpage request.

I have public wireless access.  I would like to keep it free but append/inject ad code to every port 80 or webpage request.  Would a proxy software handle this?  I would like to keep this open source not some paid server or high end software if all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer probably goes against the aim of the software, but you should take a look at [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) and its [filter capabilities](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/filter-file.html). For this to work on a public hotspot, you would need to make it intercept traffic - using something like [PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html). Alternatively, you could check out commercial software/hardware on [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=public%20hotspot%20software).